# How do you multiply out integer powers in a symbolic expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following problem:

I want to transform integer powers into a series of multiplications within symbolic expressions.
E.g. `x^3` should be written as `x*x*x`.
I tried applying the rule `a_^b_ -> a a^b-1` with a `ReplaceRepeated`, but Mathematica "simplifies" this again to `x^3`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use `NonCommutativeMultiply`, or any other inert head for your intermediate representation of powers as products, and convert back at the end, when you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x^3 //. (a_)^(b_) -> HoldForm[a]*a^(b - 1)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
x^3 + 2*x^2 - 3*x + x*y^2 + y^3*x^5 //. (a_)^(b_) ->  HoldForm[a]*a^(b - 1)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can you explain that behavior?

Comment: @Stefan What behavior? Have you checked the `HoldForm` doc page?

Comment: yes I did but would still not come to your solution. I just find yours pretty interesting. Sorry bothering you.

Comment: @Stefan There's no bothering, don't get me wrong. I'm just trying to find out the source of your apparent puzzlement. You can consider `HoldForm` as `Hold` with a cloacking device. Does that help?